# Any examples of ERC-20 tokens that pay out recurring dividends?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

Can someone provide a working example (.sol contract would be best) of a company or organization that issues their own ERC-20 token contract that pays out a regular periodic dividend (recurring transaction) to holders?

Comment: [Polymath](polymath.network) has security tokens, not sure if their has functionality to pay dividends.

Answer (score 1):

Such tokens are called security tokens. Since security tokens are treated as securities, they must be issued in accordance with the Securities Act.

Read the article below.
https://www.investopedia.com/tech/2018-year-security-token/

Comment: this is a very general answer about terminology. please comment more on ERC-721 (security) tokens specifically. some technical insight on how to develop and deploy such a smart contract (security token) would be more helpful